# How to accept and display images in java swing with (.fits) extension and perform blob detection?

Tags: java, swing, image-processing, astronomy

(.fits) Flexible Image Transport System (FITS) is an open standard defining a digital file format useful for storage, transmission and processing of scientific and other images. FITS is the most commonly used digital file format in astronomy.

Comment: [A quick google for Java Fits](https://www.google.com.au/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=java+fits&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=ixdQWumYDcPN8gfo7JmIAg) brings up some interesting possible solutions - what you're looking for is any library which can return a `java.awt.Image` or equivalent - You might find that you need to convert the titles of the FITS image into a `BufferedImage` yourself

Answer (score 1):

From the [description of the `javax.imageio` package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html#package_description).

> All implementations of `javax.imageio` provide the following standard image format plug-ins:
>
> - JPEG
> - PNG
> - BMP
> - WBMP
> - GIF

Although FITS is not included, Java imaging uses a Service Provider Interface to allow adding support for other image formats. To do that, find or write a class that can understand the CODEC, then make it available to the Java imaging API via the SPI.

### See Also

[Writing Image I/O Plug-ins](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/imageio/spec/extending.fm1.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can find a good library and documentation here: https://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/ here you can find java specific libraries: https://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/fits_libraries.html

Answer (score 0):

From [list of libraries](https://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/fits_libraries.html) for handling FITS you can choose for example [eat.fits](https://swift.gsfc.nasa.gov/sdc/software/java/).

Then you can get:

```
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(path, "r");
RandomAccessFitsFile fitFile = new RandomAccessFitsFile(file);
FitsHDU hdu = fitFile.getHDU(0); //here may be other layer. but for image is standard first
FitsImageData imgData = (FitsImageData) hdu.getData();

FitsImageViewer image = new FitsImageViewer(imgData );
```

Where FitsImageViewer extends JPanel, so you can add it to JFrame and display yout FITS image.